# Vector graphics implementations in java

Tags: java, graphics, 2d, vector-graphics

I am currently trying to make a game using java, and I wanted to use vector graphics to avoid the blocky feel of many other current games. I've looked into using some of the various `Shape` implementations in java like `Path2D` and `Area`. The problem is is that neither one has all the functionality I need. Here is what I am looking for:

1. I need to be able to create it using vector graphics based methods (`lineTo()`, `moveTo()`, etc.)
2. I need to be able to draw it onto a JPanel
3. I need to be able to test whether two instances intersect, or at the very least, whether one contains a point.
4. Finally, I need to be able to merge them together or subtract one from another.

I know this is kind of a long shot, but I was hoping someone might know of a library or something that has this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

As far as libraries go, I don't have an answer. 
I might have missed a point, but as far as I know, Graphics2D Shapes and areas have all the functions you listed. What do they lack you need ?

Of course, JavaFx has all you asked for, but if you want to write a Swing app:

I did not use them for a game, but for an editor, and here is what I would suggest:

- create your own graphic element class. Use Shapes and area to implement them, and make them Composite elements.
- for collision, have a getArea() method on your elements. The area can be the union of all areas. that represent your element.
- in real life, it might be a bit slow, however... Consider doing some pre-rendering as bitmap pictures (maybe when starting the game, when you know the resolution ?)